# Raspberry Pi FTP

Tags: ftp, webserver, raspberry-pi

Whenever I try to upload files to my Raspberry Pi web server, I get the following messages:

```
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to XXXXXXXXXXX...
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Why is this? :(
I cannot seem to be able to figure it out. I'm running Apache on Debian.

Yes, Port Forwarding has been set up on my router and it's working perfectly. I'm getting this:
    It works!

```
This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
```

I tweaked a few files here and there to modify permissions, but thus far nothing. :(

Comment: raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Apache is a webserver, not an FTP server ^.^

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```